# How to filter a dataframe using a condition that requires referencing a slice of a multi-index column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

Suppose we'd like to filter a dataframe with conditions that refer to a slice of a multi-index column, here is a toy example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
ix = pd.IndexSlice

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array([[1, 2, 3, None], [None, 2, 3, 4]]).T,
                  columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a', 'x'), ('b', 'y')]))
# this gives
      a     b
      x     y
0     1  None
1     2     2
2     3     3
3  None     4
```

I would like to filter this dataframe with a condition that resembles my real use-case:

```
df[df.isnull().any(axis=1) | df[ix[:, 'x']].isin([2])]
=> TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

or even:

```
df[df.isnull().any(axis=1) | df[df.columns[df.columns.droplevel(0).isin(['x'])]].isin([2])]
=> ValueError: cannot join with no overlapping index names
```

I would like to apply such a filtering criteria but paying attention to the fact that the columns level 0 should be ignored when looking up the column name.

I have also tried:

```
df[df.isnull().any(axis=1) | df[(slice(None), 'x')].isin([2])]
=> TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second condition return one or multiple columns DataFrame, so is possible add `any` for Series mask:

```
df1 = df[df.isnull().any(axis=1) | df.xs('x', axis=1, level=1).isin([2]).any(axis=1)]
```

Or:

```
df1 = df[df.isnull().any(axis=1) | df.loc[:, ix[:, 'x']].isin([2]).any(axis=1)]
```